# ATT Dialog don't show

Tags: swift, appdelegate, appstore-approval, apptrackingtransparency

I'm on finish with my app and recently I send it on review for AppStore. I received message about App Tracking Transparency. So i tried to implement below code in my app but dialog pop-up dont show. Please help.

```
import Foundation
import AppTrackingTransparency
import AdSupport

class AppTrackingManager {
    static func requestPermission() {
        guard #available(iOS 14, *) else { return }
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                switch status {
                case .authorized:
                    // Tracking authorization dialog was shown
                    // and we are authorized
                    QonversionManager.setAdvId()
                    print(ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier)
                    print("ATT: Authorized")
                    // Now that we are authorized we can get the I
                case .denied:
                    // Tracking authorization dialog was
                    // shown and permission is denied
                    print("ATT: Denied")
                case .notDetermined:
                    // Tracking authorization dialog has not been shown
                    print("ATT: Not Determined")
                case .restricted:
                    print("ATT: Restricted")
                @unknown default:
                    print("ATT: Unknown")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So i've created class for tracking and then i calling this func in my didFinishLaunch method in AppDelegate but nothing happens. Also i have this parameter in Info.plist
[image]

Comment: call this method requestPermission. from the main queue

Comment: it didn't help at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: I moved the request function into initial view controller